# Extending local Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I'm trying to base a `Dockerfile` on another local one.

```
$ ls -lR
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 me     me      42 14 avr 10:42 Dockerfile
drwxr-xr-x  3 me     me      42 14 avr 10:42 prod

./prod:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 me     me      42 14 avr 10:42 Dockerfile

$ cat prod/Dockerfile
FROM ../Dockerfile
...

$ docker build - < prod/Dockerfile
```

> unable to process Dockerfile: unable to parse repository info: repository name component must match "a-z0-9*(?:[._]a-z0-9*)*"

I know that `FROM` expects an image and not a path.

How can I extend `Dockerfile` from `prod/Dockerfile` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at `multi-stage` builds it could help you

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/
- https://blog.alexellis.io/mutli-stage-docker-builds/

Comment: It seems to me that multi-stage builds are too specific took it the wrong way: it allows to prepend instructions to a Dockerfile while most of the time one needs to append those.

Comment: In general, this would have been much more general to allow something like `FROM xxx AS my_container` and further in the file `FROM my_container` so that instructions can be handled individually.

Answer (score 23):

Dockerfiles don't extend *Dockerfiles* but *images*, the `FROM` line is not an "include" statement.

So, if you want to "extend" another Dockerfile, you need to build the original Dockerfile as an image, and extend that image.

For example;

Dockerfile1:

```
FROM alpine
RUN echo "foo" > /bar
```

Dockerfile2:

```
FROM myimage
RUN echo "bar" > /baz
```

Build the first Dockerfile (since it's called `Dockerfile1`, use the `-f` option as docker defaults to look for a file called `Dockerfile`), and "tag" it as `myimage`

```
docker build -f Dockerfile1 -t myimage .

# Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072 kB
# Step 1 : FROM alpine
#  ---> d7a513a663c1
# Step 2 : RUN echo "foo" > /bar
#  ---> Running in d3a3e5a18594
#  ---> a42129418da3
# Removing intermediate container d3a3e5a18594
# Successfully built a42129418da3
```

Then build the second Dockerfile, which extends the image you just built. We tag the resulting image as "myextendedimage";

```
docker build -f Dockerfile2 -t myextendedimage .

# Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072 kB
# Step 1 : FROM myimage
#  ---> a42129418da3
# Step 2 : RUN echo "bar" > /baz
#  ---> Running in 609ae35fe135
#  ---> 4ea44560d4b7
# Removing intermediate container 609ae35fe135
# Successfully built 4ea44560d4b7
```

To check the results, run a container from the image and verify that both files (`/bar` and `/baz`) are in the image;

```
docker run -it --rm myextendedimage sh -c "ls -la ba*"

# -rw-r--r--    1 root     root             4 Apr 14 10:18 bar
# -rw-r--r--    1 root     root             4 Apr 14 10:19 baz
```

I suggest to read the [User guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/intro/), which explains how to work with images and containers

Comment: Thank you, I knew that `FROM` expects an image and not a `Dockerfile` path (as I was saying in my question). I wanted to know how to extend a `Dockerfile` to improve environment configuration maintainability. But I have my answer now: No you can't :)

Comment: oh boy, haha, completely missed that in your question; yes, it's not possible (at least, not at this moment), unless you use an external tool / script to do so

Comment: Yeah I'm beginning to think about keeping my Dockerfiles as is, and using [dconf](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd) for my different environments

Comment: It depends what you need to change; in most cases, configuration should not be part of your image, but something you pass at runtime (either through environment-variables, bind-mounting a configuration file, or indeed something like confd.). In some cases, you may want to build a different image; also think of using build-time arguments (`ARG`), which can be useful for that

Comment: To configure the docker environment, use `docker-compose`. It is meant to build multi-container systems, but also offer an easy way to configure the environment variable etc. Use volumes to store config files if they need to be customized for each container, or add a bash script to configure your env at container start up.

Comment: Thank you @thaJeztah for the `ARG` tips. Yes @MrE that's what I'm doing already. What I need to find now is how to substitute my environment variables in my conf files. That's why I'm looking at confd like tools.

Comment: i usually run a script on start up that uses `sed` to replace whatever variable in the files to be changed. confd is not well maintained as far as i can tell, and it has other dependencies. unless you need to change variables along the lifetime of your container, i would not use confd

Comment: @thaJeztah is there a way to do the build automatically using docker-compose? Using your described approach I would need to build the base image manually first, and then build everything else in docker-compose.yml. I would like to have everything done in one step/command instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If you use Docker 20.10+, you can do this:

```
# syntax = edrevo/dockerfile-plus

INCLUDE+ ../Dockerfile

RUN ...
```

The `INCLUDE+` instruction gets imported by the first line in the Dockerfile. You can read more about the dockerfile-plus at https://github.com/edrevo/dockerfile-plus

Answer (score 4):

I wrote simple bash script for this. It works next way:
Example structure:

```
|
|_Dockerfile(base)
|_prod
  |_Dockerfile(extended)
```

Dockerfile(extended):

```
FROM ../Dockerfile
...
```

Run script:

```
./script.sh prod
```

It merges your base dockerfile with extended and build merged file.
Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
fromLine=$(head -n 1 $1/Dockerfile)
read -a fromLineArray <<< $fromLine
extPath=${fromLineArray[1]}
tail -n +2 "$1/Dockerfile" > strippedDocker
cat $1/$extPath strippedDocker > resDocker
rm strippedDocker
docker build - < resDocker
rm resDocker
```

Comment: This is an idea, I'll give it a try

Comment: Dockerfile shoud not extend dockerfiles but images!

Comment: @Auzias the question about extending exactly dockerfile. I agree that it bad idea because It make layer cache useless. Bit my script just merges two dockerfiles. I just showed that it's possible.

Comment: The cache should still be used as it is based on the content of the file (which will be the same)

Comment: content of which file?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using conditionals:

### Dockerfile

*Install `sudo` only on local build.*

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ARG APP_ENVIRONMENT=local

RUN apt-get update && bash -c "set -ex ; \
  apt-get install -y $([ ${APP_ENVIRONMENT} = local ] \
    && echo 'curl sudo' \
    || echo 'curl' \
  )"

CMD bash -c "set -ex ; \
  [ ${APP_ENVIRONMENT} = local ] \
    && { app debug ; exit $? ; } \
    || { app start ; exit $? ; } \
  "
```

### Build

```sh
# Production
docker build \
  -t my-image \
  --build-arg APP_ENVIRONMENT='prod' \
  .

# Local
docker build \
  -t my-image \
  .
```

### Docker Compose

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        APP_ENVIRONMENT: "${APP_ENVIRONMENT:-local}"
```